# Simple question about Paul Cohen's book "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

On page 11 of section 4, under the heading Proof, Cohen writes:

> But $\neg A(c)$ does lead to a contradiction since $A(c)$ is valid and hence by Rule F so does $\exists x \neg A(x)$.

I'm not sure how Rule F is being used. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need the following *tautology* :

> $A(c) \to (\lnot A(c) \to (B \land \lnot B))$;

due to the fact that the *contradiction* $B \land \lnot B$ is always *false*, the formula is always *true* (check it with truth table...).

Thus, if $A(c)$ is *true* (*valid*, according to Cohen's), then we can "detach" the consequent of the previous tautology by *modus ponens*, getting :

> $\lnot A(c) \to (B \land \lnot B)$.

Now we can apply Rule F to conclude with :

> > $\exists x \ \lnot A(x) \to (B \land \lnot B)$

and we have the sought conclusion, i.e. :

> "that $\exists x \ \lnot A(x)$ lead to a contradiction".